# Prove XOR doesn't work for finding a missing number (interview question)?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

Interview question: you're given a file of roughly one billion unique numbers, each of which is a 32-bit quantity. Find a number not in the file.

When I was approaching this question, I tried a few examples with 3-bit and 4-bit numbers. For the examples I tried, I found that when I XOR'd the set of numbers, I got a correct answer:

```
a = [0,1,2] # missing 3
b = [1,2,3] # missing 0
c = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] # missing 7
d = [0,1,2,3,5,6,7] # missing 4

functools.reduce((lambda x, y: x^y), a) # returns 3
functools.reduce((lambda x, y: x^y), b) # returns 0
functools.reduce((lambda x, y: x^y), c) # returns 7
functools.reduce((lambda x, y: x^y), d) # returns 4
```

However, when I coded this up and submitted it, it failed the test cases.

My question is: in an interview setting, how can I confirm or rule out with certainty that an approach like this is not a viable solution?

Comment: Not sure about "in an interview setting" but I suppose you must think of a counterexample. Any list of length 1 will fail.

Comment: Oh wow yea, that's a pretty good counterexample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all your examples, the array is missing exactly one number. That's why XOR worked. Try not to test with the same property.

For the problem itself, you can construct a number by taking the minority of each bit.

**EDIT**

Why XOR worked on your examples:

When you take the XOR for all the numbers from 0 to 2^n - 1 the result is 0 (there are exactly 2^(n-1) '1' in each bit). So if you take out one number and take XOR of all the rest, the result is the number you took out because taking XOR of that number with the result of all the rest needs to be 0.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on "that's why XOR worked"? Is there some property of XOR that has to do with one target number?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a 64-bit system with more than 4gb free memory, I would read the numbers into an array of 32-bit integers. Then I would loop through the numbers up to 32 times.

Similarly to an inverse ”Mastermind” game, I would construct a missing number bit-by-bit. In every loop, I count all numbers which match the bits, I have chosen so far and a subsequent 0 or 1. Then I add the bit which occurs less frequently. Once the count reaches zero, I have a missing number.

**Example:**

The numbers in decimal/binary are

```
1 = 01
2 = 10
3 = 11
```

There is one number with most-significant-bit 0 and two numbers with 1. Therefore, I take 0 as most significant bit. 
In the next round, I have to match 00 and 01. This immediately leads to 00 as missing number.

---

Another approach would be to use a random number generator. Chances are 50% that you find a non-existing number as first guess.

Comment: I appreciate your response. However, I'm not looking for the solution to the problem as part of this question

Answer (score 0):

Proof by counterexample: 3^4^5^6=4.

Comment: For completeness, combine with 999,999,996 distinct other 32-bit numbers, chosen to xor to zero.